# Finding maximum and minimum of $f(x)=x^{2}+e^x$

Tags: calculus

Finding maximum and minimum of $f(x)=x^{2}+e^x$

The first derivative of this function is $f'(x)=2x+e^{x}$. Set the derivative equal zero we have:

$2x+e^{x}=0\implies e^{x}=-2x \implies \ln(e^{x})=\ln(-2x) \implies x=\ln(-2x)$

I am stuck here. Is there anyway to solve this equation analytically?

Comment: Well, clearly there is no maximum. The minimum has to be $x<0$.

Comment: Can you use the LambertW function?

Comment: You can use it and I will learn something new :)

Comment: Honestly, the LambertW function appearing in any context usually means numerical approaches are the way to go. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-ProductLog(1%2F2)) value is where the function is minimized.

Comment: Should you be focusing on a particular domain? For example, $[0,1]$? If not, I don’t think your equation can be solved analytically (it couldn’t anyways, but if the domain is restricted, you could possibly still give a solution and justify it).

Comment: Which numerical method can I use to solve this equation?

Comment: You can get a very solid approximation by using $e^x\approx1+x+x^2/2$ and solving a quadratic then you get $x\approx -0.35425$ and then $f(x)\approx 0.82719$ and the real minimum is $\approx 0.82718$ which isn't far from the approximation.

Comment: @James: using numerical estimations for the Lambert W function is the most straightforward.

Comment: It is $$x=-{\rm W} \left(1/2\right)$$ the solution of your equation $$2x+e^x=0$$

Comment: @kingW3: Does this method of approximation justified? You just truncate the Taylor series for $e^{x}$ at $\frac{x^{2}}{2}$?

Comment: @kingW3: The solution to the quadratic $1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2} is $-1+i$ and $-1-i$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Can you show in more steps how do you find this result $x=-W(1/2)$

Comment: You forgot to add the 2x (Or I forgot to mention), anyway you'd need to justify it but the minimum occurs for $0<x<-1/2$ hence the $x^n/n!$ gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: @kingW3, I don't quite understand your comment above, you said add $2x$ into $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Well $f'(x)=2x+e^x=0$ and $e^x\approx 1+x+\frac{x^2}2$ hence you get $2x+1+x+\frac{x^2}2=1+3x+\frac{x^2}2=0$

Comment: @kingW3 Does this method of approximation work for other instances? I mean using Macclaurin series to approximate the maximum and minimum?